# c# convert general type to date type in export excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, export

I am using EPPlus library to export excel file from datatable, three of columns of datatable are date type and when i export the file , i find out the type of all columns are general so i have to change type manually,

This is my code :

```
DataTable Export_DT = LoadExportDataTable();


string fileName = "Report _" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm").Replace(" ", "_").Replace(":", "") + ".xlsx";
string filePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("../ExcelFiles"), fileName);
                using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName);
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(Export_DT, true);
 
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    pack.SaveAs(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
                
Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl(@"~\ExcelFiles\" + fileName), true);
```

I have tried the following solution:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Export_DT.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < Export_DT.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (Export_DT.Columns[j].ToString().Equals("START_DATE") || Export_DT.Columns[j].ToString().Equals("END_DATE") || Export_DT.Columns[j].ToString().Equals("LOCKING_DATE"))
        {
            ws.Cells[i, j].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
        }
    }
}
```

and also this:

```
ws.Column(8).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM";
```

but nothing changes!

datatable columns :

```
USER_NAME || USER_TYPE || CATEGORY || STATUS || START_DATE ||  END_DATE || LOCKING_DATE
```

What can I do?

Comment: Is the START_DATE and END_DATE columns in excel set to DataTime, Text, or General Format?  What is the connection string being used by EPPlus?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29476770/11508705), may be helpfull to you.